# Printing JSON object from javascript function on glassfish server log

Tags: javascript, java, json, nashorn

Scenario: Java servlet running on glassfish 4.1/jdk1.8.45. There is a javascript function being read from Database and executed on server side using javax.script.*. When trying to debug this function, it is desired to output some json objects on server log.It is printing [Object object] instead of the actual JSON.Tried using JSON.stringify(), it gives[undefined].
Is there a way to print the actual contents on the json object in this scenario?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

JSON.stringify works only javascript objects. It does not work on Java objects. Please make sure that you're calling JSON.stringify on a JavaScript object.

If you do need to make JSON string on a java object, you can use Object.bindProperties extension (https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+extensions#Nashornextensions-Object.bindProperties) to bind properties of the Java object to a script object and then call JSON.stringify on the same.

Sample (test) code is here -> http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/dev/nashorn/file/0de67a63e2c7/test/script/nosecurity/treeapi/utils.js

This script is used to convert a Nashorn AST tree object [a Java object] as friendly JSON object.

Comment: Yes, I am using stringify inside JavaScript not java. I want the debug statements to be printed from inside the JavaScript function.

Comment: That part - calling JSON.stringigy inside script is fine. My question is about the argument you're passing to JSON.stringify! Is that a Java object as argument or a script object? If you got "undefined" for JS object, that sounds like a bug. If it is Java object, then it is as designed.

Comment: ok.. I misunderstood.The argument is js object. 
 var fullJson = formDataHolder.getFullJson(),
  ignoreList = getIgnoreList();
  groupKey = parseInt(req.__ctrl__groupKey),
  itemKey = parseInt(req.__ctrl__itemKey),
  validateGroup = parseInt(req.__ctrl__validateGroup),
  validateItem = parseInt(req.__ctrl__validateItem),
  reviewRequested = 'review' in req,
  showReview = false,
  returnJson = {},
  vItemCheck = validateGroup+'.'+validateItem,
  itemCheck = groupKey+'.'+itemKey;

After some manipulation I am trying to print returnJson .
Thanks for your help!

Comment: In that case, you may want to isolate to a simple test and file a bug [assuming other implementations do return proper string for that case or you inferred from spec. that the value should not be undefined]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use JSON.stringify and it gives undefined, does it mean JSON is undefined or just the function? 
If so, it may be that Nashorn doesn't have it in the box. Maybe try and add it as a polyfill: you can have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) or [here](http://bestiejs.github.io/json3/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with strings in the Nashorn scripting engine then there is a probability they are Java strings rather than javascript strings. The fix is to convert your Java strings to Javascript strings.

```js
// this string does not work with stringify()
var javaString = someMethodReturningAJavaString();

var jsString = new String(javaString);

// now stringify() works:
var myJson = JSON.stringify({'key': jsString});
```

If `typeof(new String(javaString))` returns `object` rather than `string` then use `new String(javaString).valueOf()`. For some values this seems to be the only solution with [Mozilla's Rhino js engine](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Documentation).

If you have numbers then you might need to wrap java objects in the the `new Number()` constructors.

For details on the Nashorn engine have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/javascript.html